# How to add custom buttons to Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

Like today,clear and close button, I want to add some more buttons to this datepicker but I was unable to do so with use of append as its a popup datepicker so content is not loaded until we click the icon, is there some simple way to add buttons to this datepicker. 
[image]

Comment: UI Bootstrap datepicker supports complete customization. This is described in documentation (override the template).

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

Good to find the ' today,clear,close' buttons and add your button code and  click event.

Plan B:
   You can use the [timeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function to wait the date picker was loaded.
   Add append the code for your custom button functions.

Comment: Thought of plan B but it wont look good if the button appear after few seconds and for Plan A, I need 6 buttons there are only 3.